# Flask confusion with app

Tags: python, flask

I am starting a `flask` project, and in my code I have

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, abort
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Now what exactly is `app`?

I am following [this guide](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) and I am particularly confused about the structure because he has chosen to have directory named `app/` and is his `app/__init__.py` he has

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from app import views
```

and in his `app/views.py` he has

```
from app import app
```

What the hell is it with all these `app`'s?!

Comment: Those are just names and the types of the objects should be clear, can you re-state/clarify your question?

Comment: What is being imported in the `from app import app`?

Comment: Same problem here with me, This guide is not clear.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I think the main confusion is in the line:

```
from app import app
```

You have a python package (a folder with `__init__.py` file) named "app". From this folder, you are now importing the variable "app" that you defined below in `__init__.py` file:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Rename the folder from app to say "myproject". Then you will call

```
from myproject import app
```

Also, you will import views as

```
from myproject import views
```

Answer (score 17):

The author made his code needlessly confusing by choosing a package name that is the same as Flask's usual application object instance name.  This is the one you'll be most interested in:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Here is the documentation on the Flask application object:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#application-object

To avoid confusion, I recommend using the [official Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/) instead of that guide.

Answer (score 6):

That's a bit confusing indeed, due to the poor names choice.

- `app = Flask(__name__)`: here `app` is a [WSGI](http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) application, it implements the corresponding interface and also supports whatever Flask has to offer us on top of that.
- `from app import app` : imports exactly that `app` object from the package `app`.
- `from app import view`: For what heck he's importing `views` there, is a bit of a mystery, I suppose he wants to make sure that the view bindings are executed. (I'd rather do that in `run.py`). In any case, that's a kind of importing loop between two modules which is at least confusing as well.