# Flask: "from app import app"?

Tags: python, web-applications, flask

I'm following [this tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms) to make a basic Flask app:  and I don't understand the line of code in **app/view.py** that says `from app import app`. In that line, what do both of the `app` refer to? Do they both refer to the same thing?

Note: I know that there is a folder called app, and that there is an object

```
app = Flask(__ name__) in __ init__.py
```

if that helps...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flask confusion with app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486370/flask-confusion-with-app)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means:

> from package `app` import object `app`

So the first `app`is the name of the package (which is a folder with a `__init__.py` file inside) and the second is the name of the imported object from that package. See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486370/flask-confusion-with-app) for more info.