# from app import app ImportError: cannot import name 'app'

Tags: python, html, flask

flask-mega-tutorial and I found some error when I execute my code.
first I have *init*.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from app import routes
```

then routes.py

```
from app import app

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"
```

And last I have microblog.py to execute my code

```
from app import app

app.run(debug=True)
```

but when I execute FLASK_APP = microblog.py then flask run, I found this

> - Serving Flask app "microblog.py"
> - Environment: production WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
> - Debug mode: off Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
>
> Error: While importing "microblog", an ImportError was raised:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "e:\skripsiku\flask\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 235, in
>   locate_app **import**(module_name) File "E:\skripsiku\microblog.py",
>   line 1, in  from app import app ImportError: cannot import
>   name 'app'

Oh and lastly there is my folder structure. I have main folder named skripsiku then in there I have app folder (in : init.py, routes.py) and microblog.py. Can anyone help me? thank you

Comment: So how is the folder structure? It is a bit tiresome to research the folder structure of the flask mega tutorial in order to answer your question.

Comment: I have main folder named skripsiku then in there I have app folder (in : _init_.py, routes.py) and microblog.py

Comment: You should edit your question and put that there in a readable form. Questions are harder to answer if the reader has to pick all the information from the comments.

Comment: misnaming your package init file as init.py or using only a single underscore either side will cause this error. It should be named \_\_init\_\_.py (note the two underscores before and after init)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

from app import app as appl

you can use any name in place of appl

Comment: I tried that but same error was occured,

from app import app as appl
ImportError: cannot import name 'app'

Comment: did you go through this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486370/flask-confusion-with-app

Answer (score 0):

The directory for that tutorial is

[image]

minus the pycache and .vscode.

According to the tutorial, FLASK_APP=fua.py or microblog.py in your case.
I am assuming that you did `flask run` in the `C:\xampp\htdocs\FUA App\app>` directory since I faced a similar error when running that command from that directory.

I solved the problem by running the command from the `C:\xampp\htdocs\FUA App`.